# Exits when I try to use Do Loop

Tags: vbscript

I have been trying to use Do Loop, but for some reason when the code encounters the do loop command, it just exits. It doesn't even give me any errors. There is a good amount of scripting after this statement but it doesn't get processed and executed. Is there an alternative method I could use or am I just doing it wrong?

```
Do while b = vbRetry
msgbox "Remote Keyboard Control accepted from ip 346.195.639.63"
msgbox "Attempting to Block Connection..."
b = msgbox("Could not block connection.", vbCritical+vbAbortRetryIgnore+vbSystemModal)
Loop
```

Answer (score 5):

The issue is due to the fact that you didn't initialise `b` properly. The very first thing that the `while` statement does is evaluating the loop condition. In your case, the following happens:
 - `b` is undefined.
 - Is `b` is equal to `vbRetry`? No, let's stop the loop (before even starting it).

Since you need to loop at least once, you should rewrite your script as follows:

```
Do 
  msgbox "Remote Keyboard Control accepted from ip 346.195.639.63"
  msgbox "Attempting to Block Connection..."
  b = msgbox("Could not block connection.", vbCritical+vbAbortRetryIgnore+vbSystemModal)
Loop while b = vbRetry
```

Which means "Loop at least once, then check if b is equal to vbRetry".

Please note that I'm not 100% sure that the syntax is correct, I haven't used vbScript in a while (no pun intended).